# Using DEBUG_NEW correctly

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, mfc

Can someone please clarify if I must add this code to the top of all my CPP files, or will it be sufficient if only one CPP file defines it?

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place this macro at the top of every translation unit<sup>1</sup> for which you wish to [track memory allocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/mfc-debugging-techniques#BKMK_Tracking_memory_allocations). Macros are in effect from the point where they are defined to the end of the currently compiled translation unit (unless they are undefined prior to the end).

Also note that there's a [`__FILE__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) macro involved, which already is a strong hint that the (non-compliant) replacement of `new` is per-file.

---

<sup>1</sup> *[Translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) are the input to the compiler for which it generates object code. You can roughly think of a translation unit as a preprocessed source file (commonly with a file extension of .cpp, .cc, or .cxx).*